# How to import CSV to an table on BigQuery using properly

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-3.6, import-csv

I have a python script that execute a gbq job to load a csv file f to table on BigQuery. all data writes to one column but
i want  it to be loaded it in each column.i am tried autodetect but it did not help too.
my csv:

```
id,first_name,username,last_name,chat_username,chat_id,forward_date,message_text
231125223~Just~koso~swissborg_bounty~-1001368946079~1517903147~test
481895079~Emerson~EmersonEmory~swissborg_bounty~-1001368946079~1517904387~picture
316560356~Ken Sam~ICOnomix~swissborg_bounty~-1001368946079~1517904515~Today
```

this is my code:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '***.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC'] = 'True'

from google.cloud import bigquery
dataset_name = 'test_temporary_dataset'
table_name='table_telega'
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
table = dataset.table(table_name)
#table.reload()
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = 'text/csv'
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
job_config.autodetect = True

job_config.allow_jagged_rows=True
job_config.allow_quoted_newlines=True
job_config.fieldDelimiter='~'
with open('tele2.csv', 'rb') as source_file:
    #job = table.upload_from_file(source_file, source_format='text/csv')
    job=bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table, job_config=job_config)

job.result()
```

and this is what i get :
[image: bigquery]

how to load csv properly column by column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autodetect can only work with:

1. comma
2. pipe
3. tab

Tilde won't work with autodetection. You'll need to specify the schema, or change your delimiters to one of the above.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#csv_delimiter) for more info.

Comment: thanks for response , i changed delimiter to |   and now i am getting the following error  :   google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Invalid schema update. Cannot add fields (field: string_field_8)

Comment: please open a new question for that so it's easier to track and accept this one ;-)

Comment: sure , link to new question -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662949/cannot-add-fields-while-impor-ting-csv-to-an-table-on-bigquery