# Cannot add fields when importing CSV to a table in BigQuery

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, google-bigquery

I have a python script that executes a gbq job to load a csv file f to table in BigQuery. I am trying to upload data in csv format and getting the following error:

```
 400 Invalid schema update. Cannot add fields (field: string_field_8)
```

this is my csv:

```
    id,first_name,username,last_name,chat_username,chat_id,forward_date,message_text
    231125223|Just|koso|swissborg_bounty|-1001368946079|1517903147|tes
  481895079|Emerson|EmersonEmory|swissborg_bounty|-1001368946079|1517904387|pictu
    316560356|Ken Sam|ICOnomix|swissborg_bounty|-1001368946079|1517904515|Today
```

this is my code:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '***.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC'] = 'True'

from google.cloud import bigquery
dataset_name = 'test_temporary_dataset'
table_name='table_telega'
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
table = dataset.table(table_name)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = 'text/csv'
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.fieldDelimiter='|'
job_config.allow_jagged_rows=True
job_config.ignoreUnknownValues=True
job_config.allow_quoted_newlines=True
with open('**.csv', 'rb') as source_file:
    #job = table.upload_from_file(source_file, source_format='text/csv')
    job=bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table, job_config=job_config)

job.result()
print(job.result())
```

how to fix it? what should I change ?

Comment: The headers of your CSV file have 8 fields, while the content have 7.

Comment: It looks like the name "string_field_8" is autodetected by BigQuery, as you set autodetect to True and didn't provide a schema.

Comment: Yes, the previous comments are right. This happens when you load them into an existing table and there is a difference in the number of fields (schema mismatch). I tested it and you can bypass it adding a pipe delimiter at the end of each row or use a different table instead. Also, I would use the same delimiter for the Header row.

Comment: I noticed that your delimiter in the header (`,`) and data (`|`) are different. Perhaps you should make them equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

Just add this line in your code

```
job_config._properties['load']['schemaUpdateOptions'] = ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION']
```

and this will allow column addition to your existing schema.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of job_config.autodetect = True, you set it = False.

Comment: Could you add a little bit of an explanation about why this answers the question?